# How can I select and iterate through multiple rows from the database in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to select many rows from my SQL Server database and combine them in a certain manner.  Currently, I've been using the following method to get these rows:

```
SqlDataSource mySource = new SqlDataSource("ConnectionString","SelectStatement");
IEnumerable myEnum = mySource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
IEnumerator myCount = myEnum.GetEnumerator();
while(myCount.MoveNext()) //Iterate through each row
{
    DataRowView myView = (DataRowView)myCount.Current; //This is the current row
    //Do something with this row
}
```

I feel like there must be a better way of doing this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: In your code it seems you're simply iterating over your returned rows. This is trivial and could be achieved by 1001 different ways using different data access technologies. Now, how do you want to combine them? This seems to be the more interesting aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use foreach instead? foreach is meant to work on Enumerable types.
something like:

```
foreach (var currentView in mySource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty))
{
     // Do something with currentView (may need to give it a type if you are interested in it)
}
```